# Call a Python function from c++ using boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I have a python script `script.py` containing a function `hello` that simply prints `Hello World`. I would like to call this function in my c++ program using boost python module. Below is what I have done so far which is working fine and verifies my setup is working. Can someone please guide me how can I execute the function from within my c++ program contained in the python script ?

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <cstdlib> // setenv
int main()
{
  // Allow Python to load modules from the current directory.
  //setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
  // Initialize Python.
  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    python::object main_module = python::import("__main__");
    python::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    python::object print = python::exec("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n", main_namespace);

  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }

  // Do not call Py_Finalize() with Boost.Python.
}
```

Comment: `python::exec("hello()", main_namespace)`?

Comment: You haven't even tried yet.  Try it.

Comment: This is how my modified code looks now:
`python::object my_python_class_module = python::import("script");`
`python::exec("hello()", main_namespace);`

But I get the error saying: NameError: name 'hello' is not defined

Comment: Perhaps you want to `boost::import` your module instead of `"__main__"`, or maybe `python::exec("from script.py import hello")` or something.